# Variance of squared random sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, variance

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables and $N$ be a random variable supported on $\{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$ and independent on the $X_i$ .

How can I compute $Var\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^N X_j\right)^2\right]$ ?

Comment: Use the [Law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), expand the expectations carefully and use $E[X_i^aX_j^b]=E[X_i^a]E[X_j^b]$ when  $X_i,X_j$ are independnet

Comment: Thanks a lot @Henry, I was hoping there was a shortcut for this or a generic expression.